# Chrome doesn't detect gamepad?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, gamepad

I'm trying to use xbox cloud on ubuntu with the chrome web browser. I have a redragon gamepad. It works fine with firefox but for some reason chrome doesn't recognize it. Any ideas? Thank you.

```
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               lucas@atenea 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ------------ 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Kernel: 5.15.0-56-generic 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Uptime: 21 mins 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Packages: 2803 (dpkg), 27 (snap) 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Shell: bash 5.1.16 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Resolution: 1600x900 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   DE: GNOME 42.5 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM Theme: Adwaita 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Theme: Yaru-blue-dark [GTK2/3] 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Icons: Yaru-blue [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Terminal: gnome-terminal 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 1500X (8) @ 3.500GHz 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      GPU: AMD ATI Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Memory: 2026MiB / 7898MiB 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`                                   
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.

                                   



Bus 001 Device 008: ID 045e:028e Microsoft Corp. Xbox360 Controller  
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing 

Device Descriptor:  
  bLength                18  
  bDescriptorType         1  
  bcdUSB               2.00  
  bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class  
  bDeviceSubClass       255 Vendor Specific Subclass  
  bDeviceProtocol       255 Vendor Specific Protocol  
  bMaxPacketSize0         8  
  idVendor           0x045e Microsoft Corp.  
  idProduct          0x028e Xbox360 Controller  
  bcdDevice            1.10  
  iManufacturer           1 ShanWan  
  iProduct                2 XBOX 360 For Windows  
  iSerial                 0  
  bNumConfigurations      1  
  
  Configuration Descriptor:  
    bLength                 9  
    bDescriptorType         2  
    wTotalLength       0x0030  
    bNumInterfaces          1  
    bConfigurationValue     1  
    iConfiguration          0  
    bmAttributes         0x80  
      (Bus Powered)  
    MaxPower              500mA  


Interface Descriptor:   
  bLength                 9  
  bDescriptorType         4  
  bInterfaceNumber        0  
  bAlternateSetting       0  
  bNumEndpoints           2  
  bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class  
  bInterfaceSubClass     93  
  bInterfaceProtocol      1  
  iInterface              0  
  ** UNRECOGNIZED:  10 21 10 01 01 24 81 14 03 00 03 13 02 00 03 00  

  Endpoint Descriptor:  
    bLength                 7  
    bDescriptorType         5  
    bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN  
    bmAttributes            3  
      Transfer Type            Interrupt  
      Synch Type               None  
      Usage Type               Data  
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0020  1x 32 bytes  
    bInterval               4  
  Endpoint Descriptor:  
    bLength                 7  
    bDescriptorType         5  
    bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT  
    bmAttributes            3  
      Transfer Type            Interrupt  
      Synch Type               None  
      Usage Type               Data  
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0020  1x 32 bytes  
    bInterval               8
```

Comment: Is a device `/dev/input/js#` created when you connect the gamepad? Can you share the output of `lsusb -v` for your gamepad?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @guiverc !  
• **OS:** Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64  
• **Kernel:** 5.15.0-56-generic  
• **CPU:** AMD Ryzen 5 1500X (8) @ 3.500GH  
• **GPU:** AMD ATI Radeon RX 550 640SP / R  
• **Memory:** 7898MiB  
• **Gamepad:** redragon horrow g808

Comment: Thank you for your answer @nondebug !
I paste the output in the post. I can see devices in that directory with the name js#

Comment: It's pretending to be an Xbox360 USB controller so I think it should work. Maybe you have too many gamepads connected? Chrome can see at most 4 gamepads at a time. Try disconnecting all gamepads, then reconnect the Redragon gamepad.